# how to import existing repository which is available in local machine in Bitbucket

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I have a source code which is downloaded from bitbucket.  I want to import the sourcecode to my new repository and I should have all the previous changes should effect.  I want to use visual studio as IDE.

Note : I have the code in my local machine which is downloaded from another use's bitbucket.

Thanks,
Ganesh. K

Comment: 1. Add new repository as a remote. 2. Push your code there.

Comment: See here: [Import an existing Git project into Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add remote

```
 git remote add new_remote_name https://host.com/repo.git
```

Verify remotes list:

```
git remote -v
```

Push to that remote:

```
git push new_remote_name local_branch_name
```